# Why browser on webkit core bad compress images of browser-image-compression lib?

Tags: ios, image, safari, compression, webkit

Why browser on webkit core bad compress images of browser-image-compression lib?
If i compress image on browsers with blink core - image good compressed (2000px x 2000px, 160Kb). If i compress image on browsers with webkit core (sarari on iOS, google chrome on iOS) - image is too large (more then 2Mb)

I want to see smaller image size (200-300Kb) when i compress image on browser on webkit core